# Spring integration @Gateway reply timeout

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an integration like below, I call this method from rest controller, but reply timeout is not working as I expected.

What I expect: If there is no response during the time I have given for the Reply timeout, it is to return timeout as a response to the client.

Is there something that needs to be done for Timeout durations in channel configurations?

Thx.

```
@Gateway(requestChannel = REQUEST_CHANNEL, replyChannel = RESPONSE_CHANNEL, requestTimeout = 5000, replyTimeout = 5000)
Mono<ResponseObject> sendRequestObject(RequestObject request);

@Bean    
public IntegrationFlow myRequestFlow() {     
     return IntegrationFlows.from(REQUEST_CHANNEL)
           .enrichHeaders(HeaderEnricherSpec::headerChannelsToString)
           .handle(message -> {
               // I didn't send anything on the response channel.
               System.out.println(message);    
            })
           .get(); 
       }  

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myResponseFlow(MessageChannel myResponseChannel) { 
     return IntegrationFlows.from(myResponseChannel)
               .channel(RESPONSE_CHANNEL)
               .get(); 
       }
```

Comment: Please, share with us how it works then. Note: the `replyTimeout` comes into a force only when `send()` part of the gateway is finished. So, if the send is blocking for a while, the reply behavior might be as expected as it sounds. See the `replyTimeout` JavaDocs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I am not getting any response for this situation. It waits forever.
I'll review your document again.
My sender channel is not blocked, even I use the handle method to test it and just print the log.
If I understand correctly and I didn't make any configuration mistakes, I think it should have worked for the following situation. Because in the following situation, I do not just log and get a response.

Comment: Sorry, this is not readable. Please, consider to edit your question with respective code snippets and explanations how it works and what is expected.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I edited the question about it.

Comment: Thanks, but why don't you say what is the current behavior?

Comment: The current behavior is I wait forever if I don't get any response when I call the sendRequestObject method. Nothing is returned when the replyTimeout expires.

Comment: Good. Looking into that. Thank you!

Comment: Wait. How you may wait there if you use `Mono` return. It comes back to you immediately. Then you use the `Mono` operators to deal with the data. Although I guess you just return it back to the client via your rest controller. I don't think it is already Spring Integration responsibility to set limits for that `Mono` processing.

Answer (score 0):

The current default behavior of the `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` is to return `null` on reply timeout. The logic is like this:

```
if (reply == null && this.errorOnTimeout) {
            throwMessageTimeoutException(object, "No reply received within timeout");
}
```

That `errorOnTimeout` is `false` by default and I don't see that we have a hook from annotations to configure it. Feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter.

Anyway I don't see that a `replyTimeout` is involved in the `MonoReplyChannel`. So, that one could be another improvement from the gateway perspective.

But I still think that your web client should set some request timeout to not wait indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for be interested,

For the same situation,

For spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.5.RELEASE and spring-integarion-core:5.1.5,
When the replyTimeout expires, the response is returned as null.

However

For spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.3 and spring-integarion-core:5.5.8,
The situation I was talking about happened.

Maybe there are things I missed, I will examine it in detail.

Comment: That Spring Boot and Spring Integration are out of support already. Anyway it would be great to see some simple project from you to play with. Reproduce and work out a robust solution.